# How to specialize a class-member for multiple template values (constants)?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'd like to specialize a member-method of a template-class. This template-class has a constant template-parameter of type int and depending on the value different global variables have to be selected:

```
template <int INSTANCE>
class mailbox
{
public:
    void write(uint32_t v);
}

// global accessors of different instances
extern mailbox<0> mailbox0;
extern mailbox<1> mailbox1;
```

and later in a .cpp-file

```
template<>
void mailbox<0>::write(uint32_t v)
{
    access(reg_0, v);
}

template<>
void mailbox<1>::write(uint32_t v)
{
    access(reg_1, v);
}

mailbox<0> mailbox0;
mailbox<1> mailbox1;
```

This allows me to use the mailbox as follows:

```
mailbox0.write(0xdeadcafe);
```

This compiles and links. I'd like to simplify the method by using the constant INSTANCE:

```
template<int INSTANCE>
void mailbox<INSTANCE>::write(uint32_t v)
{
    if (INSTANCE == 0)
        access(reg_0, v);
    else
        access(reg_1, v);
}
```

But I'm unable to figure the right syntax to make it work. Is this at all possible while keeping my user-code as is? What are the right words and terms for what I want to do in C++-slang?

Comment: `template<int INSTANCE> void mailbox<INSTANCE>::write(uint32_t v)`

Comment: You *do* know how to define member functions of templated classes? Is there not something missing between `mailbox` and `::` in the non-working example?

Comment: I would suggest to read up on C++17's `constexpr if`, if you can use 17 of course. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I added an example of user code, which even with the requested version does not change.

Comment: @MarošBeťko Normal `if` would work just fine here if the definition syntax were correct. `if constexpr` will help optimisation by ensuring the false branch does not have unreachable code generated, but otherwise provide no semantic difference.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the problem just that you are trying to separate a template into .h and .cpp (which, in reality, is rarely feasible in the current standard)?

```
template <int INSTANCE>
class mailbox
{
public:
    void write(uint32_t v){
        if (INSTANCE == 0)
            access(reg_0, v);
        else
            access(reg_1, v);
    }
}
```

should work

Comment: I'd love to hide `reg_0` and `reg_1` and `access` from the user.

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible at the moment. At least the interface of those will need to be accessible if you want to use a template. Even in your first example `mailbox<2>` will not compile

Comment: That's the goal, have mailbox<2> compile error or at least link-error out.

Comment: Then your first solution is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could go other way around - let global variable be a static member of a class parametrized by the same int mailbox is parametrized by. e.g.:

```
template <int INSTANCE>
struct reg {
    static RegType value;
};

template <int INSTANCE>
RegType reg<INSTANCE>::value;
```

then access to the reg value would be transparent without any specialization:

```
template<int INSTANCE>
void mailbox<INSTANCE>::write(uint32_t v) {
    access(reg<INSTANCE>::value, v);
}
```

---

If c++17 is in a game you can make a reg template global variable and let the code be even simpler:

```
template <int INSTANCE>
RegType reg;

template<int INSTANCE>
void mailbox<INSTANCE>::write(uint32_t v) {
    access(reg<INSTANCE>, v);
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If you can't modify the access pattern you could create array of reference wrappers (c++11):

```
#include <functional>

std::reference_wrapper<RegType> regs[2] {reg_0, reg_1};

template<int INSTANCE>
void mailbox<INSTANCE>::write(uint32_t v) {
    access(regs[INSTANCE].get(), v);
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, but `reg_1` and `reg_0` and `access` are provided as is to me. I can't change it.

Comment: Instead of using std::reference_wrapper, which inhibited the compiler to inline the code, I now use a simple `const RegType regs[]`-array. And I index it with `INSTANCE`.

Comment: @PatrickB. this should work for you as long as regs are not mutable betwean accesses